# How to prevent SentinelOne antivirus from flagging nvm.sh?

Tags: anti-virus, node.js, anti-malware, nvm

The recommended installation instructions for the node version manager (nvm) are to download and run the `install_nvm.sh` bash script, which creates the `~/.nvm` folder, and the nvm script, `~/.nvm/nvm.sh`. On a macOS system protected with SentinelOne anti-malware software this triggers SentinelOne to alert and quarantine (i.e. remove) `nvm.sh`.

Does NVM represent in some way a legitimate threat? If not, is there a way to stop SentinelOne from quarantining it?

The affected versions of NVM are 0.39.0, 0.39.1, 0.39.2, 0.39.3 (current, as I write this question).

To reproduce, run the NVM installer script on macOS (13.4).

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`

Look for a SentinelOne (22.4.2.6599) notification message to popup:

"Threat detected. Detected malicious file. File Name nvm.sh"

Edit: more details ...

Using code bisection of nvm.sh, I found that the presence of just two or three lines saved in a file with a .sh extension is sufficient to trigger SentinelOne.

A file with these minimal lines is sufficient to trigger SentinelOne quaratine:

```
cat > nvm.sh
1166:    if command printf "${SEEN_ALIASES}" | nvm_grep -q -e "^${ALIAS_TEMP}$"; then
6416:    command chmod +x "${VERSION_PATH}"/node.exe || return 1
```

OR these three lines:

```
cat > nvm.sh
5112:      printf "%d%06d%06d\n", a[1], a[2], a[3];
6415:      command mv "${TMPDIR}/"*/* "${VERSION_PATH}" || return 1
6417:      command chmod +x "${VERSION_PATH}"/npm || return 1
```

I suppose that these lines are not particularly objectionable, but that this is the result of an automatically generated malware signature algorithm.

Comment: Can you whitelist the script - look at the threat in Sentinel One and see if that provides a way to whitelist.

Comment: I don't see a way to whitelist a threat in SentinelOne, but I'm open to suggestions if someone know how that process is supposed to go.

Answer (score 1):

This Sentinel One article appears to provide a way.

[Sentinel One Whitelist](https://www.sentinelone.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/SentinelOne-Whitelisting-and-Blacklisting.pdf)

> SentinelOne’s robust exclusion function is easily configured to enable
> compatibility and remedy  interoperability false positives. Exclusions
> can be applied at the global level, site level and group  level for
> granular control. Blacklisting or whitelisting specific applications
> is not a requirement  in order for the SentinelOne solution to
> operate. However, it is considered best practices to  ensure that no
> other endpoint security solutions may be conflicting with SentinelOne
> and  thus cause interoperability issues. In such cases, it is advised
> that customers consider the use  of exclusions to deal with 3rd part
> interoperability conflicts. SentinelOne is happy to discuss  mass
> deployment strategies that include testing for potential
> interoperability issues and  proactively handling them. SentinelOne
> agent exclusion mechanisms include:  • Hash value • Path, path +
> subfolders, specific executable • Signer certificate identity • File
> type • Browser type The ability to not monitor certain executables as
> well as the option to use cascading exclusions. The latter is
> typically used by shops building code that use known-good compilers.
> We also  have multiple exclusion modes for highly specific (surgical)
> exclusions. Ability to turn on and off  functionality for
> consideration of different deployment scenarios, including throttling
> of deployment. All guidelines and knowledge base articles can be
> access via the online customer portal.

Comment: This seems plausible. I haven't been able to confirm setting up an exclusion as the SentinelOne installation is institutionally managed. I will update when I'm able to confirm that this works.